# Display PDF - Application Page SharePoint

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

I am working on a Custom WebPart, for which I need an application page to render a PDF file.

I am currently using following link http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306654

It works fine in ASP.NET, but gives a blank page in SharePoint.

Here's the code: 
(PDF file is in same directory)

```
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.ClearHeaders();
        //Set the appropriate ContentType.
        Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf";
        //Get the physical path to the file.
        string FilePath = MapPath("Test.pdf");
        //Write the file directly to the HTTP content output stream.
        Response.WriteFile(FilePath);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
```

Working on it for last few hrs, making me crazy...any ideas?

Comment: The problem might be this line : string FilePath = MapPath("Test.pdf"); . Are you sure the file exists there (when running under sharepoint)?

Comment: @Raj: That's not the issue. File is in the same folder. Also, I am facing same issue in case I am writing PDF using a Byte array, its working in ASP.NET.

Comment: I realize it works in ASP.NET but is your web part even executing in Sharepoint? Remove all code from the web part and put Response.Write("hello"). Does the line execute?

Comment: @Raj: Yes Response.Write does work. Also, the code to render PDF is just on Application Page. If I try to access application separately without webpart, then also I cannot see PDF.

Comment: Comment Response.WriteFile(Filepath); Add Response.Write(Filepath); Lets see if it is at least able to get the file path.

Comment: ..your code above is inside Render, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few ideas:

1. If the file is in the SharePoint directories, why not just redirect to a URL for it?
2. If you use Fiddler (or Firebug) to look at the HTTP traffic -- do you see the content-type change? What is the content (is it a PDF?)
3. The main differences between SharePoint and ASP.NET (assuming that you are getting to the file correctly) is that the page life-cycle is slightly different and the security model.  You might want to look at how `Reponse.End()` works to make sure it isn't different in SharePoint.  You can run SharePoint in verbose logging and then use .NET Reflector on the SharePoint dlls (with the logs as a guide) to see if there's some weird way of handling this.  The SharePoint dlls have pretty liberal log calls.  More info here: http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/archive/2008/06/11/SharePoint-Debugging-and-Logging-Tips-and-Tricks.aspx
4. Have you considered rasterizing the PDF and just showing it inline in the page? This is what we do in a project my company is working on to view PDF and other documents in SharePoint ([Vizit](http://www.atalasoft.com/products/vizit-sp/vizit-reader)). You still have to solve your problem of reading the file, but instead of responding with the PDF, you respond with a PNG and request inside of an `<img>` tag.

Comment: Thanks for answer Lou. I will be checking this over the weekend and update you then. Planning to checking debugging option as of now.

Comment: Issue turned out to be corrupt PDf installation. Thanks for your help.